# Parse array to string?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$test`.

```
print_r($test) :

Array ( [0] => aa 
        [1] => cc 
        [2] => bbb )
```

What is the best method for parse this to get the string:

```
aa, cc, bbb
```

I want this string in variable the `$parse`.

Comment: this will help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$string = implode(', ', $your_array);
```